# rotate the image 90 degrees

Tags: android, image, rotation, 360-degrees

Is it possible to rotate the image **90 degrees**

Note : the rotation is not in `ImageView` object , but in The original image in the path
With many thanks

```
      public void Rotate90 (){ 

//      Rotate90 this       File image1= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/0Students/Compressed_Images/t12.jpg" );
    }
```

Comment: do you mean rotate image from file and save it again ??

Comment: do you mean rotate image from file and save it again? yes And thank you for your response

Answer (score 2):

first load your image from file

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image Path);
```

then make a matrix

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap , 0, 0,
                bitmap .getWidth(), bitmap .getHeight(),
                matrix, true);

then save it to your system 



   private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and don't forget to add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

hope this help you :)

Comment: Thank you for this help and I really appreciate it,
But compress function change the image resolution even to put 100%, 
I hope to get  another way without  compress  function 
With the most beautiful greetings

Comment: unfortunately , as far as I know there is no other way but if you don't want to lose quality replace this finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out); with this finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);  as PNG is lossless refer to following link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/4q3lxOlZKRQ

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="kitten" class="" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
  </body>
</html>
javascript.js:

let image = document.querySelectorAll("#kitten")
image.onclick = toggleClass;

function toggleClass(){
  if(image.className == 'image'){
      image.className = ''
  } else {
      image.className = 'image'
  }
}

styles.CSS:
#kitten {

    position: absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:60%;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
}

.image{
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);} }
@-webkit-keyframes spin {100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);} }
@keyframes spin {100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg);} }

 still my image is not rotating after clicking on image can any solve it?
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, when answering questions please make sure to provide description of what code as well, this might help a lot more to OP than just plain code because he will understand why it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

Check with **setRotation(float)** API

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)

Comment: Thank you for your response, there is no example of a work function

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to get the bitmap from your path like this:

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

2) Pass myBitmap to this function for getting 90 degrees rotated image

```
public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  matrix.postRotate(angle);
  return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```